# Return element actual property width % not px IE

Tags: internet-explorer, mootools

CRAZY!! 
seriously, every other browser returns what is actually written in property style , how can I get the width as is defined in css style ?

```
<div id="mywidth" style="width:50%">Div div</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var mydith = $('mywidth').getStyle('width');

document.write(mydith);​ // 50%
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fGjR/2/

Comment: use .getCoordinates().width or .getSize()

Comment: @DimitarChristoff  I need to return % in all browsers , .getCoordinates().width  returns px getSize also

Comment: oh i thought you wanted px not %. soz. erm - somebody was doing stuff like that on the irc channel a week or so ago, think it may be a plugin for this being done. will look it up

Comment: After testing this a bit, seems it's a bug in the normalization code for IE as it converts anything that's not in px back to pixels, so this will also "break" if you use other units (em for example). I will try picking this up over github, I'm actively working towards getting a more stable Element.Style